# How to define jQuery scroll settings?

Tags: jquery

My problem is extremely simple: I have to modify a jQuery `scrollTo` call on existing code in order to execute a callback function after the scroll has completed (some hundreds of milliseconds).

I found [this article](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) that explains the scrollTo method. But I don't know how to pass settings too!
I already have a function to call, so how do I call it after scroll has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.scrollTo( $('#item'), 800, function(){
     callToYourFunction();
});
```

Comment: Damn, I thought it would have been pretty difficult involving special classes or named arguments........... :) hahahaha

Comment: Yeah it's pretty simple. You just pass the function as a parameter. Happy coding!